# Firebase OTP SMS has two codes, one for verification and another that's always the same for all users

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase Auth, we released the app a few days ago, and the verification SMS used to be as expected the standard template of Firebase, but starting from today the SMS message contains additional code/characters, this ab example:

> 123456 is your verification code for MyApp.
>
> L9dioiHOViq

the long code is the same for all users, and it is confusing the users, anyone can help, please??
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Frank, but they are suggesting changing my app name on google play so that so the msg exceeds 53 characters to hide the hash. is there any other way that I can do to hide the hash without changing my app name?

Comment: The hash is explained here too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential. I'm not aware of any way to change this.